# Move files from one bucket to a folder inside another bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, boto3

I am new to boto3 and am able to move files from one bucket to another bucket but, I need to move files inside a folder in another bucket

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'move' command in Amazon S3. Instead, you will need to:

- Use `copy_object()` to copy the object to a new `Key` (which includes the full path of the object)
- Then `delete_object()` on the old object

The destination for the copy can be the same bucket or a different bucket.

Folders do not really exist, so you can **copy an object to *any* path** without first creating the folders.

If you don't need to use boto3, a simpler method is to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket1/foo/object.txt s3://bucket2/bar/object.txt
```

You can even move whole 'folders':

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket1/foo s3://bucket2/ --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

With boto3, it's pretty simple. As described in the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy):

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')
```

And after you copy your file from one bucket to another one, you can delete it:

```
obj = s3.Object('bucket_name', 'key')
obj.delete()
```